Generating Python code with RedBaron, using path as a variable
I'm using RedBaron to generate Python code. I need parts of the generated code to be variables, passed from generating code. This works well with, for example, integers and such. But when I try to pass path as a variable, it fails.
Example code:
from redbaron import RedBaron

def generate_code(path):
    code = ("This is a path: {}".format(path))

    red = RedBaron(code)
    print(red.dumps())

output_path = "C:\\test\\folder"
generate_code(output_path)

I've tried f-strings, raw strings, Python 2 compatible strings as I've found that RedBaron can't integrally parse Python 3 (whatever that means). I still get various errors, related to RedBaron being unable to find matching token for "\":
File "C:\Python31\Lib\site-packages\baron\tokenizer.py", line 127, in tokenize_generator
    raise UnknowItem("Can't find a matching token for this item: '%s'" % item)
baron.tokenizer.UnknowItem: Can't find a matching token for this item: '\'

When the path is hardcoded, it works fine.
Hardcoded example:
"\tmyFunction(folderPath=r'C:\\\\Folder_1\\\\Folder_2\\\\Folder_3')\n"

Is there a way to use path as variable in a code generated by RedBaron?

The documentation seems to suggest you need to pass valid python code, and a backslash isn't valid code unless quoted. Can you show what you mean by hard-coded? Maybe you use path = '{}'.format(path) to create an assignment expression?

@OneCricketeer I've updated the question

That's valid code... As mentioned ,try assigning a variable within the string like folderPath = 'r"{}"'.format(path), then" myFunction(folderPath=folderPath). Otherwise, you could open and read a separate Python file
